# Is it possible to make a subclass of NSObject which support subnodes in IB for iPhone project?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsobject

I'm making a custom UI element class for iPhone.
It'll cool to edit my class on Interface Builder with hierarchy.

Some of my class is management class like UINavigationController, but they're not one of them, subclassed from NSObject.

Of course, I can place a NSObject instance on IB, but it cannot have a child node.
Is there a way to enable adding child node to subclass of NSObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a plug-in for Interface Builder.  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), or, more specifically, [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/DesigningControlsViews/DesigningControlsViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004323-CH3-SW1).

Matt Gallagher also has a nice tutorial [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/custom-views-in-interface-builder-using.html).

Now, these links all pertain to Mac.  I honestly am not sure if the same principles apply to iPhone.